# What happened to the site?

Tags: discussion, design

I'm not really sure, but today StackOverflow looks uglier than before. Can't quite say what changed but the overall feel is clear, looks like someone tried to make it "modern" and "flat". Ugh.

Was there some design change? If so, why?

I liked it much better before!

Comment: Uglier than before, do you mean that it looked ugly before.

Comment: Less pretty = uglier

Comment: You do realize that is a completely subjective thing, right?

Comment: Well the typography and syntax highlighting is seriously messed up, font so thin I can barely see it, it looks very much like when Google decided it's time to overhaul gmail. Ever since I had to zoom and use plugins to make it readable.

Comment: Just a line for stackoverflow: "Bring Back Trebuchet Ms"

Comment: Oh ok, this is really bad. Why did it go live if it's so broken?

Comment: btw not sure how this can be duplicate of the other post, if the changes happened just today. That one is from november!

Comment: @MightyPork read the other post...

Comment: I did (some of it, there's too many comments). But many people complain and YET is is in production now, without fixing the obvious issues. I can tell CSS is half-baked when I see it. This definitely is not finished.